# Why does my filter function in Bash not work?

Tags: shell-script

I wrote a *filter* / *select* function that takes a function and a stream as input. It should yield a new array of ( 2 4 ). However, my result is nothing. I suspect it has something to do with the IFS.

```
# func int -> bool
is_even () { (( $1 % 2 == 0 )) ;}

# func func -> int
filter () {
  local function_to_apply=$1
  local arg

  while read -r arg; do
    $function_to_apply $arg && echo $arg
  done;:
}

# int array
integers=( 1 2 3 4 )  
result=$(echo "${integers[*]}" | filter is_even)
declare -p result
```

Output is a string `""`

```
declare -- result=""
```

Expected Output is an array of `( 2 4 )`

```
declare -a result ='([0]="2" [1]="4")'
```

---

Give credit where credit is due:

http://www.binaryphile.com/bash/2018/07/26/approach-bash-like-a-developer-part-1-intro.html

Comment: At least two problems: 1. `while read -r arg` expects one argument per line, but you dump them all on the same line with `echo "${integers[*]}"` 2. `result=$(...)` doesn't create an array, but a simple variable.

Comment: @muru Yes, I also thought so because `read -r` will read until the next newline (which `echo` appends to its output). I also confirmed  this by inspecting arg `declare -p arg` inside of the function. I more or less copied the code from here: http://www.binaryphile.com/bash/2018/10/31/approach-bash-like-a-developer-part-36-functional-programming.html. I was surprised that it could work that way. I was hoping for an explanation here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You give your function input on a single line. The line will be the string `1 2 3 4` which is what `"${integers[*]}"` expands to with the default value of `$IFS`. This entire single line will be read by the first call to `read` into `arg` and used (unquoted) in a call to your function.  Since `$arg` is unquoted, the shell will spit the string on the spaces and your function will only use that initial `1`, which is not even.  This means that the `echo $arg` is not triggered.

Instead:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

is_even () { (( $1 % 2 == 0 )) ;}

filter () {
  local function_to_apply="$1"
  local arg

  while read -r arg; do
    "$function_to_apply" "$arg" && echo "$arg"
  done
}

integers=( 1 2 3 4 )  
result=$(printf '%s\n' "${integers[@]}" | filter is_even)
declare -p result
```

The main thing here is to print the elements of the array on individual lines to the `filter` function.

This will give you the single string `2\n4` (where `\n` is a newline).  This should be no surprise as you are assigning a string to `result`.

If you want to get an array back, you can do this in a recent release of `bash`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

is_even () { (( $1 % 2 == 0 )) ;}

filter () {
  local func="$1"
  local -n in_array="$2"
  local -n out_array="$3"

  local element

  out_array=()
  for element in "${in_array[@]}"; do
    if "$func" "$element"; then
        out_array+=( "$element" )
    fi
  done
}

integers=( 1 2 3 4 )
even_ints=()

filter is_even integers even_ints
declare -p even_ints
```

This is using two name reference variables inside the `filter` function.  The first one is the input array and the second one is the output array.

This will give you the output

```
declare -a even_ints=([0]="2" [1]="4")
```

Another way to pass the values to the `filter` function is obviously to pass them on the command line of the function:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

is_even () { (( $1 % 2 == 0 )) ;}

filter () {
  local func="$1"
  local -n out_array="$2"
  shift 2

  local element

  out_array=()
  for element do
    if "$func" "$element"; then
        out_array+=( "$element" )
    fi
  done
}

integers=( 1 2 3 4 )
even_ints=()

filter is_even even_ints "${integers[@]}"
declare -p even_ints
```

Comment: `printf '%s\n' ${integers[*]}` is equivalent to `printf '%s\n' "${integers[@]}"` it seems, regardless of `$IFS`.

Comment: @JonathanKomar Yes, since you don't quote `${integers[*]}`, which is bad style. In the general case (i.e. when the type and format of the data in the array is not know at all, possibly because it was provided from outside the script), your unquoted expansion would trigger both splitting on white-spaces and filename globbing.  If you quote it (you should quote all expansions), the first character of `$IFS` will be used as a delimiter between the array's elements. The two commands are not equivalent if you have elements that contain spaces and/or filename globbing patterns.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** @Kusalananda's `filter` won't be able to filter an array in place; if the same array is given as both the source and the destination, it will just truncate it.

That could be easily fixed by rewriting the function as this:

```
filter() {
        local cb=$1 i j a; local -n src=$2 dst=$3
        for a in "${src[@]}"; do
                "$cb" "$a" && dst[i++]=$a
        done
        for((j=${#dst[@]}; j>=i; j--)); do
                unset dst[j]
        done
}
```

**2.** However such demos/challenges (eg "How to do functional programming in bash") are **completely pointless**. Even when compared to other very high-level languages like perl or javascript, bash is incredibly slow. Using bash for parsing / filtering data instead of calling other utilities like `grep` may turn out to be orders of magnitude slower.

Using the problem from the question, a grep solution will be 3 times faster even with a puny 1000-elements array and when filtering **bash's own arrays**, not some external files. And that despite having to fork some 3 processes and exec an external binary. See the example below (using a 100000 elements array):

```
bash filter.sh 100000
=== bash_filter ===

real    0m1.037s
user    0m1.036s
sys     0m0.001s
=== grep_filter ===

real    0m0.302s
user    0m0.226s
sys     0m0.189s
```

**filter.sh:**

```
is_even () { (( $1 % 2 == 0 )) ;}
bash_filter() {
    local cb=$1 i j a; local -n src=$2 dst=$3
    for a in "${src[@]}"; do
        "$cb" "$a" && dst[i++]=$a
    done
    for((j=${#dst[@]}; j>=i; j--)); do
        unset dst[j]
    done
}
grep_filter() {
    local flt=$1; local -n src=$2 dst=$3
    dst=($(printf '%d\n' "${src[@]}" | grep "$flt"))

}
timeit(){
    echo "=== $1 ==="
    time "$@" inlist outlist
    [ "${#outlist[@]}" -lt 20 ] && echo "${outlist[@]}"
}

inlist=($(seq "${1-100000}"))
timeit bash_filter is_even
timeit grep_filter '[02468]$'
```

Comment: This was never intended to be a performance contest. I recognize that Bash is slow. In some cases, its convenience (being available on virtually all of my systems-both big and small) outweighs the performance hit. Also, what you consider pointless is an exercise in programming prowess. I. value the knowledge gained simply by understanding how it *would* work. Then I am empowered to say that it is a bad idea because of x, y, and z (your conclusion).

Comment: I cannot think of a system with bash but no awk, sed, grep, sort, etc.

Comment: Did you mean to say you run that with one thousand or a hundred thousand elements? I get the same 3x-ish difference with a thousand element array too, but the absolute time is nowhere near that one second, of course.

Comment: @mosvy That is very true! I was thinking along the lines of my use case (which was left out of this question for simplicity sake), which would involve C or C++.

Comment: @JonathanKomar, portability is an issue, yes, but I'd still suggest using something like Perl or Python rather than Bash for "larger" tasks. Or awk. Not because of speed, but, well, sanity.

Comment: @ilkkachu even with 1000 elements it will be 3x faster. And 95% of the time is probably taken by marshalling the data back and forth.

Comment: @mosvy, I just mean that you wrote 1000, but right there after it the numbers are for 100000, which kinda looks confusing. And misleading: it seems to imply that processing 1000 elements would take one second, and even Bash isn't that slow :)

Comment: Why are you using an `unset dst[j]`? When is it needed?

Comment: Everytime `filter` is used with the same array as the source and the destination. Admittedly, in this case, `dst=("${dst[@]:0:i}")` would be scarequote "faster".

Comment: @isaac Where "this case" means "when the src and the dst are the same array" -- otherwise recopying the whole array just to truncate it would be DUMB

Comment: @Isaac In other words, Kusalananda uses two arrays: 1 populated for input, 1 empty for output. Mosvy offers and alternative case: use 1, prepopulated array and sort it itself (called *in-place* sorting): `arr=(1 2 3); filter arr arr`. The line `out_array=()` in Kusalananda's code would actually truncate the input array, because input and output are the same if you pass in the same array for both input and output. Mosvy did not add demo code (which is in Kusalananda's answer), which is probably why it was not immediate clear. Mosvy, feel free to correct me if I missed something.

Comment: @mosvy You never initialize integer `i` as far as I can tell e.g. `local -i i`, so how does it get initialized? to -1? I guess it gets converted implicitly from string to integer in `dst[i++]`, but where is the default value for `i` defined? For `j` it is clear that it is the highest index of the array.

Comment: There's no need to initialize it, because `local i` basically creates a new variable (shadowing any global variable with the same name) and the numeric value of an unitialized variable in bash is 0. Try with `i=7; foo(){ local i; echo $((i)); }; foo`

Comment: This is the same in other shells like zsh, yash, mksh (and also with the lexically scoped variables from ksh93 -- `function fo { typeset i; echo $((i)); }`). It also matches the behaviour of `local` in perl. __It's different in dash, though__ where the old value of a localized variable is preserved. In bash, this behaviour can be changed with `shopt -s localvar_inherit` to match that from dash, but that is not the default, and will also break `declare` and `typeset` (`local`, `declare` and `typeset` are the same thing in bash).

Comment: @JonathanKomar my function does not _sort_ the arrays, it just filters it through a function. But if you brough up sorting: writing a function to sort arrays in pure bash would probably be >100 slower than calling out to `sort(1)` even with a 100 elements array ;-)

Comment: If `i` is 0, `dst[i++]=foo` will assign `foo` to the zeroth element of `dst` and THEN increment `i`. The `i++` "post-increment" works similarly in bash arithm expressions to the way it works in C, awk, perl, java, javascript, php, etc: `i++` will increment `i`, but return the old value of `i`. So `i` doesn't have to be initially `-1`, but `0`.